# jQuery form serialize data missing in CodeIgniter with TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, tinymce

I'm using tinymce. And I'm sending data by jquery ajax call like this

```
// update textarea from tinymce
tinyMCE.triggerSave (false,true);
$.post ('', $('#page_form').serialize (), function (x){
    var ans = $.parseJSON (x);
    if (ans.success)
    {
// my work
```

but the server is getting

```
<p><span medium;="" font-family:="" \'andale="" mono\',="" times;\"="">aiwndiawnduawd </span><strong>waoid</strong></p>
```

but it should get

```
<p><span style="font-size: medium; font-family: 'andale mono', times;">aiwndiawnduawd </span><strong>waoid</strong></p>
```

I saw from js console that $('.tinymce').val () returns correct value but somehow ajax call misses the value on the fly

Anyone faced this before? or any solution?

Comment: First of all this is not jquery ajax call this jquery post call. Second thing is that .serialize method is used with forms if you provide form id with this .serialize method it will get all data of form and makes query string of it.

Comment: Do you have any idea about this issue or not? You missed giving anything

Comment: based from your code you're not submitting the data to any script in the backend plus you don't even have a form yet you're using serialize()

Comment: @raheelshan `$.post()` is a wrapper that calls `$.ajax()` so it **is** an AJAX call. Also, `.serialize()` doesn't **have** to be used with a form, you can call it on a jQuery object containing specific input elements.

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu Can't direct a comment to more than one person, but the same applies to your comment as well. You don't **need** a form to use `.serialize()`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: thanks for the correction I'm definitely learning a lot here:}

Comment: Would you possibly provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem. I'm going crazy! :-(
It seems JQuery Ajax request (I use serializeArray function) don't want accept anything like ""!!!
I'm sure that the problem isn't TinyMCE (I try to "force" string, serialize it.. and "style" disapear!).. :-(

---

(edit)

Are you using CodeIgniter framework? If yes, give a look to your *application/config/config.php* file and try to set **$config['global_xss_filtering']** parameter to **FALSE**... It works for me! :-)

If is your case, remember to use XSS filtering on POST, and GET where you must protect by scripting hack (visit [CodeIgniter XSS manual page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html)).

Otherwise try to debug by add/remove slashes (in jQuery and PHP), or manually look at the value of something like this ( before and after ajax):

```
    <input type="hidden" name="test" id="test" value="<p><span style="color:#f00;">test</span></p>" />
```

Comment: turning off XSS worked fine, so I rewrote CI's  class to turn off XSS for specific data field and it worked fine

Comment: Great work Mazhar! The solution you used is probably better than what I suggested.. I think I'll do the same!